# Accessing complex JSON data in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, nested

I tried accessing complex JSON data structures but i get this error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

This is the JSON data response im working with:

```
data = [
  {
    "id": "matic_atlantis",
    "chain": "matic",
    "name": "Atlantis",
    "site_url": "https://atlantis.loans",
    "logo_url": "https://static.debank.com/image/project/logo_url/matic_atlantis/a1334c12971c12f4796ea439fbc1c5f8.png",
    "has_supported_portfolio": True,
    "tvl": 0,
    "portfolio_item_list": [
      {
        "stats": {
          "asset_usd_value": 20.258310032314448,
          "debt_usd_value": 0.03452806117121324,
          "net_usd_value": 20.223781971143236
        },
        "update_at": 1645959230.678967,
        "name": "Lending",
        "pool_id": "0x8f85ee1c0a96734cb76870106dd9c016db6de09a",
        "detail_types": [
          "lending"
        ],
        "detail": {
          "supply_token_list": [
            {
              "id": "matic",
              "chain": "matic",
              "name": "MATIC",
              "symbol": "MATIC",
              "display_symbol": None,
              "optimized_symbol": "MATIC",
              "decimals": 18,
              "logo_url": "https://static.debank.com/image/matic_token/logo_url/matic/e5a8a2860ba5cf740a474dcab796dc63.png",
              "protocol_id": "",
              "price": 1.525962,
              "is_verified": True,
              "is_core": True,
              "is_wallet": True,
              "time_at": None,
              "amount": 0.00007212821116324932,
              "is_collateral": True
            },
            {
              "id": "0x831753dd7087cac61ab5644b308642cc1c33dc13",
              "chain": "matic",
              "name": "Quickswap",
              "symbol": "QUICK",
              "display_symbol": None,
              "optimized_symbol": "QUICK",
              "decimals": 18,
              "logo_url": "https://static.debank.com/image/matic_token/logo_url/0x831753dd7087cac61ab5644b308642cc1c33dc13/3f40a8915d99b9dd0e24d5205c89eb34.png",
              "protocol_id": "matic_quickswap",
              "price": 165.3,
              "is_verified": True,
              "is_core": True,
              "is_wallet": True,
              "time_at": 1602175296,
              "amount": 0.12255414378345482,
              "is_collateral": True
            }
          ],
          "borrow_token_list": [
            {
              "id": "matic",
              "chain": "matic",
              "name": "MATIC",
              "symbol": "MATIC",
              "display_symbol": None,
              "optimized_symbol": "MATIC",
              "decimals": 18,
              "logo_url": "https://static.debank.com/image/matic_token/logo_url/matic/e5a8a2860ba5cf740a474dcab796dc63.png",
              "protocol_id": "",
              "price": 1.525962,
              "is_verified": True,
              "is_core": True,
              "is_wallet": True,
              "time_at": None,
              "amount": 0.000002603921715322
            },
            {
              "id": "0x53e0bca35ec356bd5dddfebbd1fc0fd03fabad39",
              "chain": "matic",
              "name": "ChainLink Token",
              "symbol": "LINK",
              "display_symbol": None,
              "optimized_symbol": "LINK",
              "decimals": 18,
              "logo_url": "https://static.debank.com/image/matic_token/logo_url/0x53e0bca35ec356bd5dddfebbd1fc0fd03fabad39/69425617db0ef93a7c21c4f9b81c7ca5.png",
              "protocol_id": "",
              "price": 14.5811,
              "is_verified": True,
              "is_core": True,
              "is_wallet": True,
              "time_at": 1598767775,
              "amount": 0.000163336006690615
            },
            {
              "id": "0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174",
              "chain": "matic",
              "name": "USD Coin (PoS)",
              "symbol": "USDC",
              "display_symbol": None,
              "optimized_symbol": "USDC",
              "decimals": 6,
              "logo_url": "https://static.debank.com/image/matic_token/logo_url/0x2791bca1f2de4661ed88a30c99a7a9449aa84174/fffcd27b9efff5a86ab942084c05924d.png",
              "protocol_id": "",
              "price": 1,
              "is_verified": True,
              "is_core": True,
              "is_wallet": True,
              "time_at": 1601199611,
              "amount": 0.000054
            },
            {
              "id": "0x831753dd7087cac61ab5644b308642cc1c33dc13",
              "chain": "matic",
              "name": "Quickswap",
              "symbol": "QUICK",
              "display_symbol": None,
              "optimized_symbol": "QUICK",
              "decimals": 18,
              "logo_url": "https://static.debank.com/image/matic_token/logo_url/0x831753dd7087cac61ab5644b308642cc1c33dc13/3f40a8915d99b9dd0e24d5205c89eb34.png",
              "protocol_id": "matic_quickswap",
              "price": 165.3,
              "is_verified": True,
              "is_core": True,
              "is_wallet": True,
              "time_at": 1602175296,
              "amount": 0.000194122619712451
            }
          ],
          "health_rate": 322.6968922103766
        },
        "proxy_detail": {}
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The python code im using:

```
for i in data["portfolio_item_list"]["stats"]:
    print(i["asset_usd_value"], i["debt_usd_value"], i["net_usd_value"])
```

I'm trying to save the users portfolio data.
I've tried to search the internet for possible solutations but i'm very new to these kind of complex JSON structures and cannot find alot of data of it. I hope someone can help me out what im doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem happens because your are trying to access the data var like it's a dict in: `data["portfolio_item_list"]["stats"]` but it's a list.
You also did that on the `portfolio_item_list`.

Try this:

```
for i in data[0]["portfolio_item_list"][0]["stats"]:
    print(i["asset_usd_value"], i["debt_usd_value"], i["net_usd_value"])
```

Here, you first access the first elemt in the data array and then access the element's values.

Second thing you should do is to change the `stats` to a list like this:

```
"stats": [{
    "asset_usd_value": 20.258310032314448,
    "debt_usd_value": 0.03452806117121324,
    "net_usd_value": 20.223781971143236
}],
```

Because you can't loop through a dict like it's a list.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but i already tried that and it gives me the same error :(

Comment: Try the edited one. I noticed that the `portfolio_itrm_list` is also a list so you need to access it with an index as well.